# How to generate java docs for specific classes and specific packages, together

Tags: java, javadoc

I have to generate java docs for a project but not for all files.

I want to create index.hmtl which contains java docs for some specific classes and some specific packages.

I know how to create each of them separately but if i give two commands the last command results are shown and everything else is over written.

How to i do all of this using one command. Basically i want to club it all in one.

Thanks.

Comment: What build system do you use - if just javac and shell scripts you should look at one e.g. ant, maven, gradle that allow this sort of control

Comment: we are using ant but how does it work...i still need to know the commands.

Comment: I was hoping to have like a batch file with teh javac command to generate the docs. but the issue is that i need to do it all in one command

Comment: Which the build languages allow you to do this and more complex tasks were why they were invented. ant has the [javadoc task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) which allows you to do this. Try it and then raise a question re ant if you can\t get to to work.